# Android: Draw custom border around listview?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, drawable

I've got a ListActivity with a ListView in it.   I need to draw a repeating image around the border ("on top of it (I guess after the listview is renderered))

How can I hook in my own drawing code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a FrameLayout to cause the ListView to overlap with a view that fills the entire screen. In this background view you could tile an image, or write your own custom View with your own drawing method.

Comment: I actually did something sort of similar to this in the end and should have answered it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no border property in ListView, as far as I know.

Instead you can put ListView into a FrameLayout and set the Background color of the FrameLayout.

Finally, set some padding to FrameLayout in order to create a border effect.

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
There is one way I have used, but that can be done in XML only.
    
            
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:divider="#ffcccccc"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"/>

What I am doing is, putting listview in a LinearLayout. Background color of the list is different than that of layout. There is a margin set for layout. Hence the distance between list and layout will appear like a border for the listview.
Hope this helps.